# Fast shell command to find position of a string sequence in a big file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a ~200MB file in linux that has only 1 line. I need a command that can quickly return the first position where a string sequence occurs in that line/file.

Example: The start of the line in the file is "43525346465746123", if I input 5746, it would return 11.

I'm already using an awk command

```
awk -v find=5746 '{ printf ("%s", index($0,find) ) }' file
```

However for the 200MB file, this command takes around 6 seconds. Is there a faster way?
I also want it to return a few characters that are present before and after the sequence. In the above example they would be: 646 and 123

Comment: You could also code a small *C* program using `stat`, `open`, `mmap`, `strstr`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did eventually :)

Answer (score 1):

Try sed (I don't know how it will compare vs. awk for your data, so let us know):

```
sed -n "s/^.*(...5746...).*$/\1/p" file
```

I don't have a system to test this on now, but the here's the theory:

- `-n`: don't print every line by default (in case the search string is not found)
- `s`: substitute
- `^.*`: from the beginnning, eat all the characters, until...
- `(...5746...)`: capture the search string and some surrounding characters
- `.*$`: eat the rest of the line
- `\1`: replace the line with the capture
- `p`: print it (only if matched)

Edit: Or try grep (again, please let us know what the performance is for your data):

```
grep -o "...5746..." file
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and answer! But it is taking even longer for the 200MB file. It worked just fine on smaller ones tho!

Comment: Good to know.  Please try the "grep" version I just added too.

Comment: With grep it was taking long too, eventually I wrote a C program :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how it will scale, but you can try:

```
grep -o -P '.*?5746' | echo "`wc -m`-3" | bc
```

`-P` is needed to handle non-greedy regex, as the above without it would match the whole string till (and including) the last occurence of `˙5746`. `-o` outputs only the matched pattern, then `wc -m` counts the characters, but it containts the pattern as well, so it should be decremented (e.g. with `bc`).

Comment: Thanks, but even this is taking long